# Apps offering free data or money based on using and sharing

Tags: applications, malware

I have been hearing about some android apps which give you free money or data by installing, using and sharing. Many of my friends have been asking me to install such apps so-that they get benefits of sharing app with trying to convince me like "share to others and get free benefits". Such apps also gives benefits if you install other apps or click on some links through them.

But I've been refusing to install or use such apps thinking following reasons:

- It should be nothing but pure advertising app for app maker
- It may get our personal information like email, phone, contacts and even some may get usage and information of other apps, files etc.

But/Now, I want to know more about such apps like how do they work? what are the major and possible disadvantages (malicious, spy etc.) of using such apps, etc. so that I can keep way from  possible temptation/seduction and can preach my friends with better understanding.

Comment: I'd say both your doubts are true. Nothing can stop those unconcerned people from getting hold of that "free" money, though.

Comment: Agreeing to @AndyYan and sharing your concerns. In the best case, those apps are after your data (advertizing/profiling). Worse, they might turn trojan after being spread enough and convert your device to be a member of some bot net. I'd rather stay clear of those. If you cannot resist, at least take a very good look at the permissions requested and see if you can block "dubious ones".

Comment: Also: Most of those apps have so low returns, that the electricity is more expensive than the money you would get out of those apps (needless to say that the people behind such apps make some good cash by selling high value ads, like installing an app).

Answer (score 0):

Your concerns are 100% valid!

A few things you can consider while making a decision whether to install such apps:

-Firstly, do you really need this so called app? If not, don't install!

-Secondly, see if the app has any good/social cause which really helps people if you download the app (when i say help, i dont mean your friends getting free money), if it does, then consider helping out!

-Lastly, if you do choose to install the app, check the permissions the app is asking before installing. Try not to download from unknown sources, and do read the reviews. If you have Xiaomi phone or cyanogenmod/lineage, they usually have 'App Permissions' sections, make sure not to give the application any permissions!

Answer (score 0):

Your concerns are right. Never trust "free" apps, gifts or something else like that, because those companies always will make their profit otherwhise they wouldnt exist. Most of those apps are pure fake and some even harm your device by later install malware payloads on your Smartphone.